# How can one obtain the sizeof a type for which one has an encoding?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Given an Objective-C type `type`, one can obtain the [encoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) `encoding` and size `size` of the type easily:

```
const char *encoding = @encode(type);
size_t size = sizeof(type);
```

Put a little differently, we have mappings

```
@encode: type_t -> const char *
sizeof:  type_t -> size_t
```

This raises two questions:

(1) Suppose that rather than having a type, we have only an encoding.  It would be nice to obtain a mapping

```
sizeofencodedtype: const char * -> size_t
```

such that for every **type_t** `type` we have that

```
sizeofencodedtype(@encode(type)) = sizeof(type)
```

Does such a function already exist?  If not, how might one go about building one?

(2) Ideally we could invert the **@encode** mapping to make a mapping

```
decode: const char * -> type_t
```

but this doesn't seem to be possible since **type_t** isn't a real C type.  I guess I could wait for **@decode** to be added to the language, but that's not very realistic or time-sensitive.  But should it not be possible to instantiate a type at runtime using its encoding?

References:
[Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide - Type Encodings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[NSGetSizeAndAlignment()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW54) can do this for you. It's also a useful function if you're trying to grope through multiple types in the same string.

Comment: I spent probably two hours trying to figure out different ways of saying this and stumbled upon it from a referring question.  Thank you!