# Why can some methods (-retainWeakReference, -allowsWeakReference, +load, +initialize) on class NSObject not be added to other classes at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

It is straightforward at runtime to create a copy **MyNSObject** of the *Class* **NSObject**:

First, create a new [class pair](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html).

```
Class MyNSObject = objc_allocateClassPair(nil, "MyNSObject", 0);
```

Second read the methods, protocols, and ivars from **NSObject** and add them to the new class.

```
uint instanceMethodCount;
Method *instanceMethodArray = class_copyMethodList([NSObject class], &instanceMethodCount);
for (int i = 0; i < instanceMethodCount; i++) {
    Method method = *(instanceMethodArray + i);
    SEL selector =  method_getName(method);
    IMP implementation = method_getImplementation(method);
    const char *types = method_getTypeEncoding(method);
    BOOL success = class_addMethod(MyNSObject, selector, implementation, types);
}
free(instanceMethodArray);

uint protocolCount;
Protocol **protocolArray = class_copyProtocolList([NSObject class], &protocolCount);
for (int i = 0; i < protocolCount; i++) {
    Protocol *protocol = *(protocolArray + i);
    BOOL success = class_addProtocol(MyNSObject, protocol);
}
free(protocolArray);

uint ivarCount;
Ivar *ivarArray = class_copyIvarList([NSObject class], &ivarCount);
for (int i = 0; i < ivarCount; i++) {
    Ivar ivar = *(ivarArray + i);
    const char *name = ivar_getName(ivar);
    const char *typeEncoding = ivar_getTypeEncoding(ivar);
    NSUInteger size, alignment;
    NSGetSizeAndAlignment(typeEncoding, &size, &alignment);
    BOOL success = class_addIvar(MyNSObject, name, size, alignment, typeEncoding);
}
free (ivarArray);
```

Third, read the methods from the metaclass of **NSObject** and add them to the new metaclass.

```
uint classMethodCount;
Method *classMethodArray = class_copyMethodList(object_getClass([NSObject class]), &classMethodCount);
for (int i = 0; i < classMethodCount; i++) {
Method method = *(classMethodArray + i);
SEL selector =  method_getName(method);
IMP implementation = method_getImplementation(method);
const char *types = method_getTypeEncoding(method);
BOOL success = class_addMethod(object_getClass(MyNSObject), selector, implementation, types);
}
free(classMethodArray);
```

And finally, register the class pair.

```
objc_registerClassPair(MyNSObject);
```

Well, it's almost that straightforward.  There are a couple of problems with this.  Well, a couple of couples.  If we were to add the following lines at the end but within the first for block

```
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"unable to add method with selector named %@ to class MyNSObject", NSStringFromSelector(selector));
}
```

and the following lines at the end but within the last for block

```
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"unable to add method with selector name %@ to metaclass MyNSObject", NSStringFromSelector(selector));
}
```

Then we would see the following output:

```
unable to add method with selector name retainWeakReference to class MyNSObject
unable to add method with selector name allowsWeakReference to class MyNSObject
unable to add method with selector name load to metaclass MyNSObject
unable to add method with selector name initialize to metaclass MyNSObject
```

What is going on here?  Do classes (resp. metaclasses) implement retainWeakReference and allowsWeakReferenc (resp. load and initialize) "out of the box"?

References:
1.  [Cocoa with Love - What is a meta-class in Objective-C?](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html)
2.  [Stack Overflow - Justin Spahr-Summers response to "How can one obtain the sizeof a type for which one has an encoding?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8281744/1052673)

Comment: Weird! Are the IMPs you're getting back for those methods NULL?

Comment: Unfortunately, the IMPs are non-NULL, and furthermore, as I'm about to edit into the question, the class responds to all these selectors after objc_registerClassPair() is called on it.  Additionally, the implementations of these four methods for MyNSObject are different from the corresponding implementations for NSObject.

Comment: Woops.  There is a method with name (e.g. of the four) "initialize" on NSObject whose implementation is different from the implementation of "initialize" on MyNSObject.  However...[see answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8287409/1052673).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NSObject is an even more interesting beast than expected.  Typically one thinks about the map

```
method_getName: Method -> SEL
```

as being one-to-one.  I.e one usually thinks that `method_getName(methodA) == method_getName(methodB)` just in case `methodA == methodB`.  One is encouraged to think this: one cannot create a class during coding via `@interface` which has multiple methods with the same selector, nor can one add two methods with the same selector to a class using `class_addMethod()` during runtime.

However, it is evidently possible to do it by hand.  The following code demonstrates this.  This code gets all the instance methods on **NSObject** and prints out each one named either "retainWeakReference" or "allowsWeakReference" and then gets all the *class* methods on **NSObject** and prints out each one named either "initialize" or "load".

```
uint NSObjectInstanceMethodCount;
Method *NSObjectInstanceMethodArray = class_copyMethodList([NSObject class], &NSObjectInstanceMethodCount);
for (int i = 0; i < NSObjectInstanceMethodCount; i++) {
    Method method = *(NSObjectInstanceMethodArray + i);
    SEL selector = method_getName(method);
    IMP implementation = method_getImplementation(method);
    const char *types = method_getTypeEncoding(method);
    if (strcmp(selector, "retainWeakReference") == 0 || strcmp(selector, "allowsWeakReference") == 0) {
        NSLog(@"NSObject implements method(%s,%p,%s)", selector, implementation, types);
    }
}

uint NSObjectClassMethodCount;
Method *NSObjectClassMethodArray = class_copyMethodList(object_getClass([NSObject class]), &NSObjectClassMethodCount);
for (int i = 0; i < NSObjectClassMethodCount; i++) {
    Method method = *(NSObjectClassMethodArray + i);
    SEL selector = method_getName(method);
    IMP implementation = method_getImplementation(method);
    const char *types = method_getTypeEncoding(method);
    if (strcmp(selector, "initialize") == 0 || strcmp(selector, "load") == 0) {
        NSLog(@"metaNSObject implements method(%s,%p,%s)", selector, implementation, types);
    }
}
```

The output is not what one might, aside from the preceding build-up, have expected:

```
NSObject implements method(retainWeakReference,0x7fff8a120b1f,c16@0:8)
NSObject implements method(allowsWeakReference,0x7fff8a120b05,c16@0:8)
NSObject implements method(retainWeakReference,0x7fff80ad6db0,c16@0:8)
NSObject implements method(allowsWeakReference,0x7fff80ad6d90,c16@0:8)
metaNSObject implements method(load,0x7fff8a09e4f2,v16@0:8)
metaNSObject implements method(initialize,0x7fff8a00cb89,v16@0:8)
metaNSObject implements method(load,0x7fff80a57670,v16@0:8)
metaNSObject implements method(initialize,0x7fff80a133d0,v16@0:8)
```

So, as is now evident, NSObject has two implementations for each of the selectors `-retainWeakReference`, `-allowsWeakReference`, `+load`, and `+initialize`.  These are the only four methods on **NSObject** for which there are multiple implementations, which is demonstrated by the fact that these were the only four reported by the code in the question as being unable to be added to **MyNSObject**.

A statement which gets close to counting as an answer to the question then is that you can't add multiple methods with the same selector to a class created at runtime via `class_addMethod()`.  In particular, though, no, no methods are implemented by a class created at runtime with `objc_allocateClassPair()` "out of the box".