# How to convert NSData bytes into NSNumber or NSInteger?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdata

There's a special `NSString` `initWithData` method for grabbing bits and converting them into string.  However, I haven't found that in `NSNumber` class ref. Currently, I'm getting raw data (bytes) from a server in `NSData` format. I know how to do that in C, using `memcpy` and `int` pointers. But I am curious about what the convenience methods are for doing that straight from `NSData`.  No conversion is needed.  For example, I'm getting `00000010` byte, and I need to turn that into `NSNumber` of value 2, or `NSInteger`.

Comment: if you know how to do it in c you can do it in objective-c too. Just use those methods. Get the raw bytes with `[myNSData bytes]`. If you want you can create a category for NSNumber so you can use initWithData:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NSData` is just a bucket for bytes and has no knowledge of the data contained therein.  `NSString`'s `initWithData:encoding:` method is a reciprocal (it does the opposite) of this method:

```
- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Therefore, to answer your question fully, it's important to know how your numbers were originally coerced into an `NSData` object.  Once you know the encoding function, the search is for the reciprocal function.

From what you've included in the question, there may be a number of different solutions.  However, you'll probably be able to use something along the following lines to convert into a usable numeric format using `getBytes:length:` on your NSData object.  For e.g.

```
NSUInteger decodedInteger;
[myDataObject getBytes:&decodedInteger length:sizeof(decodedInteger)];
```

You can change the type of `decodedInteger` to whatever is appropriate for the bytes in your `NSData` object.

Comment: If your object includes more than one value, then you'll need to use `NSRange` to pull out each individual value, and use the `sizeof()` function to move your range throughout the data.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with getBytes. Though it's not the same as I expected with "initWithData", it's still more of "objective-c" style than plain c.

Comment: @Centurion When (de)serializing bytes this way, you should always take endianness into account. See `NSSwap...` family of functions in Foundation/NSByteOrder.h.

Comment: @Costique Do I still need to think about that when using getBytes? If no then how to pass that explicitly to getBytes call? Currently, I'v parsed several responses with getBytes and everything is OK.

Comment: @Centurion Yes. The reason is that the sequence of bytes representing a number in memory on big-endian and little-endian systems is different. You have to know the endianness of the serialized number to interpret it correctly. If it's working without the conversion, the endianness of your CPU and of the sending CPU is the same. But you don't want to make any assumptions, because the endianness of your bytes' source machine may change and because nothing stops Apple from making a PowerPC iPad. It's best to make this right once from the very start because fixing byte order is a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSNumber *num = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:numberAsNSData];
```

Edit:

As pointed out by Matthias Bauch this will not work in your case. This only works if your NSNumber object was archived into NSData objects.

Comment: that will only work for NSNumber objects that were archived into NSData objects

Answer (score 1):

NSString to the rescue:

```
const unsigned char *bytes = [serverData bytes];
NSInteger aValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2x", bytes[0]].integerValue;
```

The docs warn about using NSScanner for localized decimal numbers, but that's of no concern in this case.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the answer

```
//Integer to NSData
+(NSData *) IntToNSData:(NSInteger)data
{
    Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(4);
    byteData[3] = data & 0xff;
    byteData[2] = (data & 0xff00) >> 8;
    byteData[1] = (data & 0xff0000) >> 16;
    byteData[0] = (data & 0xff000000) >> 24;
    NSData * result = [NSData dataWithBytes:byteData length:4];
    NSLog(@"result=%@",result);
    return (NSData*)result;
}
```

refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20497490/562812 for more detail