# How to convert NSNumber into Bytes in ObjC?

Tags: objective-c, encoding, nsnumber

I want to get the byte value of a NSNumber, so that I can convert it to a NSData object. I need to send it as bytes over a TCP connection, so I can't encode it as UTF8 or anything else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9225065/530933

Comment: Do you need to serialize the number so it can be re-instantiated from the data via `initWithCoder:`? Or get the underlying numeric primitive?

Answer (score 4):

```
int integer = [num intValue];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&integer length:sizeof(integer)];
```

Comment: edited my answer.. yeah have to convert it... this is one of the solution